# How do i theme new Header-bar for gtk3 compnents?

Tags: unity, themes, gtk3

in my themes i do now have header-bars definiton . I don't get the ambiance code in this point. 
I did see that they aren' t exactly like normal toolbars. and don' t behave like ones.  Can someone help me how they work with left right buttons etc. A header-bar and header-barbut titlebar .css  would help much .

Schould they be handled like toolbars or do they follow the window manager  top border design ?

regards bluedxca93

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNOME Headerbars are themed using the GTK+ Theme and Icon Set that you have applied on the desktop environment you're using, so to change the theme and icons on GTK+ Headerbars, you'll need to use a Tweak Tool e.g: unity-tweak-tool to be able to change the theme. Once there, select a GTK Theme of your choice and the headerbars' look will change in rhythm and the same goes for a change of the icon set.

Or in simple terms: They should be thought of as GTK+ toolbars (With Window Buttons (if compatible))...